# Where to find the pip config file for 9.0.1

Tags: python-2.7, configuration, pip, configuration-files

I'm running python on a MBP running 10.9.5.
Python and pip are both at /usr/local/bin.
This might be a simple question with a stupid mistake on my end but I went to this [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-file) to see where the config file for pip 9.0.1 is located but I don't have a file in any of the locations it mentions:

```
$HOME/.config/pip/pip.conf
$HOME/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf.
$HOME/.pip/pip.conf
/etc/pip.conf
/Library/Application Support/pip/pip.conf
```

Before, when I had pip 8.x.x installed, it copied all module files into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages.  Python was able to see all my modules and I had no problems.

I just updated to pip 9.0.1 and it's now installing modules to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.  Now, in python, I can't import the new modules since the new modules are going to the new location and python is looking at the old location.  Can someone please tell me where the config file is located since it's not where the link says it should be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are not modifying any of the defaults, then you don't need a config file.  Hence, there is no `pip.conf` file, unless you've manually created one.

If you want one, just create the the file `~/.pip/pip.conf` (and the `.pip` directory, if necessary).